# why is there a difference between these two interaction plots

Tags: r, interaction

I was trying to see if there is any interaction between temperature variable and family variable on the photosynthetic rate (Assimilation) and for this purpose, i have generated interaction plots. When i used family on the x-axis i get no interaction and if i use Temperature on x-axis i get interaction. Which of these is correct?

Here is my code and plot for family on x-axis:

```
with(light, interaction.plot(x.factor=Family, trace.factor = Temp.group,
                             response=Assimilation, fun=mean, type="b", legend=T,
                             ylab="Assimilation", main=" Temp:Family Interaction Plot"))
```

[image: plot-1]

Here is my code and plot for temperature on x-axis:

```
with(light, interaction.plot(x.factor=Temp.group, trace.factor = Family,
                             response=Assimilation, fun=mean, type="b", legend=T,
                             ylab="Assimilation", main=" Temp:Family Interaction Plot"))
```

[image: plot-2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of these is correct?

The two plots should be showing exactly the same information.  Hopefully, they are both correct.

> When i used family on the x-axis i get no interaction and if i use
>   Temperature on x-axis i get interaction.

If you look carefully at the first plot, you can see that the two temperature profiles (across family) are not *exactly* parallel to each other.

In theory, *any* departure from parallel profiles represents an interaction.  But, it is too much to ask real data to be exactly parallel.   After all, some error in the measurements might cause some deviations even if the real process has no interaction.

The formal statistical test will be the test of the interaction term in your analysis of variance model.  If the interaction term is not significant, then there was not enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis of "no interaction effect".

You might be thinking that interaction effects mean that "the lines *have* to cross in the plots".  That is not the case.  They only need to be non-parallel.   They would cross somewhere if you extended them enough.

The second plot shows that any interaction effects are rather small.  And, the effect seems  mostly due to families 3 and 4, which deviate in opposite ways from the rest of the families.